# How to check syntax Oracle stored procedure in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, syntax, compilation, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Server Management Studio, there is a "Parse" menu where you can check the syntax of the stored procedure, without running the stored procedure.
Is there a similar thing in Oracle SQL Developer, to check the syntax of the codes in the stored procedure without executing it ? Similar to compiling it, and see if there is any error ?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the difference between *"Similar to compiling it, and see if there is any error ?"* and actually just compiling it and see if there is any error ?

Comment: How do you compile a stored procedure in SQL Developer ? Sorry, I am new to it. Thank you

Comment: You *alter* it: `alter procedure p_test compile;`

Comment: Ah..When I do "alter procedure mySP compile; It gives me "insufficient privileges" Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes...but it does that as you type, it's not an on-demand thing.
[image]

There is no...hey compiler have a look at this, but don't actually compile it feature. Our parser is client side and is following the rules of the Oracle SQL and PL/SQL syntax and applies that to the code it sees.

Comment: Thank you for your help